# Changing state in ComponentWillMount goes to an infinite loop

Tags: react-native

In my react native app i'm changing a style at a fixed time from 7 to 7:30pm. I am changing the state for that in ComponentWillMount. But whenever i go to that component,it starts calling that state again and again and doesn't even stop when i go to a different component. I want to stop this infinite loop of calling itself.
Here's the code:

```js
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
class Third extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: 0,
      live: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.focusListener = navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {
      this.changeLang()
    });
    var today = new Date()
    var time = today.getHours()
    console.log(today.getMinutes())
    var weekDay = today.getDay()
    if ((time >= 19) && (time <= 20 ) && (weekDay === 0 ||3 ||6)){
      if(today.getMinutes()<=30){
      this.setState({ live: true })
    } 
  }
  }
  async changeLang() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('toggle')
      this.setState({ toggle: JSON.parse(value) })
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    console.log('live', this.state.live)
    this.changeLang()
    return (
      <Container style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <Content>
         <Left></Left>
         <Body></Body>
         <Right>{(this.state.live === true) ? <Icon name='football'/>: <Icon name='refresh'/>}</Right>

              </View>
            </Card>
          </View>
          
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Third)
```

Here `this.state.live` keeps on giving consoles and doesn't stop. What can be done here to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this in render function,

```
this.changeLang()
```

Every time you call `this.setState` your component will re-render, and when component re-render your `render` function will get called.

So the sequence causing infinite loop is,

**Component mounts => in render function you call  `this.changeLang()` => in `changeLog` function you are calling `this.setState` => `render` function get called which again executes `this.changeLang()` => in `changeLog` function you are calling `this.setState` ... so on.**

In this way you end up with infinite loop.

Just remove `this.changeLang()` from render function as you are already calling the same in `componentWillMount`.

Comment: I'm using this.changeLang() in render because i want to change the language of the component when i change that from settings page. So, if i can't use it in render can you tell me where can i call it so that it gets called everytime i open this component? @ravibagul91

Comment: You are already calling that function inside `componentWillMount` right?

Comment: Can you explain more how `Third` component is connected to `Settings` component. Or you have scenario where you change language from setting component and then manually coming to `Third` component and by default need to call `changeLang` function?

Comment: Yes but that's not working properly. I want to change language in unmounted components also. But ComponentWillMount only works for mounted components. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: its exactly how you described. But can't figure out how to change Lang by default when comes to an unmounted component.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the use of `navigation.addListener("didFocus", () => {` in `ComponentWillMount `?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196136/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-tanmoy-sarker).

Comment: Just found a solution. Calling the function in constructor changes language for unmounted components and calling in willmount changes the mounted. So,i'm calling in both of them and it somehow works.

Answer (score 0):

Calling setState here makes your component a contender for producing infinite loops. remove this.changeLang() make it work

Comment: this.changeLang() is another thing that i will need. Is there another way other than this? @Aurangzaibrana